# Estimating a distribution from a dataset with multiple parameters

Tags: distributions, modeling, predictive-models, poisson-distribution, fitting

How would you go about solving the following problem?

You're an insurance company who writes workers compensation policies.  You want to build a probability distribution for the number of annual claims of an account based on certain characteristics.  You determine that the three most important predictor variables are the number of employees, the assigned risk level ("high", "medium", "low"), and the primary state where the business is located ("AL", "AK", ...).

You think a poisson distribution would be a good model, but if you try to build a separate model using only the data in each unique combination of the variable classes, you don't have enough data to be credible.  For instance, if you try to fit a distribution to AL, high risk accounts with 10 employees, you only have 1 or 2 observations to use.

How do people typically solve this sort of problem.  I'm sure its been done a thousand times before, but I don't have much experience with it.  Perhaps some sort of glm?  What makes it more confusing to me is how you might combine the three very different types of predictors - a numeric predictor, and ordinal factor, and a non ordered factor.

Comment: I have seen hierarchical modeling used for these types of situations. This type of modeling allows for sharing data across categories, which can improve prediction for those cases. I've not done much of it, so I'll let someone else point you in the right direction with it

Comment: I am not entirely clear on your data structure, but recall that in longitudinal designs (to which count of event models like Poisson are often applied), the sample size is actually the sum of the number of *observations* within each individual, and not simply the number of individuals.

Comment: Did you determine the three most important predictors from the data set you plan to analyze?  Or is this well known information from other sources?